# Generating Lookup Table For 3D Noise

Tags: c#, noise, lookup-tables

I'm having trouble understanding why my lookup table is not working. I currently have one that generates a table for 2D noise, which works fine.

```
int xOffset = chunk.Pos.x;
int zOffset = chunk.Pos.z;

// Generate a lookup table
int i = 0;
for (int z = 0; z<ni.noiseGen.Size; z++)
{
    float zf = (z<<ni.noiseGen.Step)+zOffset;

    for (int x = 0; x<ni.noiseGen.Size; x++)
    {
        float xf = (x<<ni.noiseGen.Step)+xOffset;
        ni.lookupTable[i++] = NoiseUtils.GetNoise(noise.Noise, xf, 0f, zf, 75f, 100, noise.Gain);
    }
}
```

When I try to iterate over a y axis, it does not work. An index out of range exception is thrown. Below is the attempted 3D lookup table.

```
int xOffset = chunk.Pos.x;
int yOffset = chunk.Pos.y;
int zOffset = chunk.Pos.z;

// Generate a lookup table
int i = 0;
for (int z = 0; z<ni.noiseGen.Size; z++)
{
    float zf = (z<<ni.noiseGen.Step)+zOffset;

    for (int y = 0; y<ni.noiseGen.Size; y++)
    {
        float yf = (y<<ni.noiseGen.Step)+yOffset;

        for (int x = 0; x<ni.noiseGen.Size; x++)
        {
            float xf = (x<<ni.noiseGen.Step)+xOffset;
            ni.lookupTable[i++] = NoiseUtils.GetNoise(noise.Noise, xf, yf, zf, 75f, 100, noise.Gain);
        }
    }
}
```

I'd assume it'd be as easy as that, but I was wrong and do not understand why. Any enlightenment would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: We would need to see how `ni.noiseGen.Size` is created, and how it relates to the X, Y, and Z values. For example if it is a cubic 3D table, the X, Y, and Z will be the same dimensionally, but if it is not cubic Y may have a different size and using `.Size` may result in an out-of-bounds. So what we need to see is what `.Size` means in relation to each dimension.

Comment: How is `ni.lookupTable` declared? Clearly in first example you fill `ni.noiseGen.Size`^2 cells and in second one you're trying to fill `ni.noiseGen.Size`^3 cells, is it long enough?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, after looking over how ni.lookupTable was declared I realized I forgot to multiply by the size one more time for 3D. It is now declared like this,

```
        ni.lookupTable = pools.FloatArrayPool.Pop(ni.noiseGen.Size*ni.noiseGen.Size*ni.noiseGen.Size);
```

My apologies!